# Как ограничить класс декоратором что бы не подменяли тип после наследования от открытого интерфейса?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, декоратор

Мне необходимо ограничить использование интерфейсов наследуемых от интерфейса `IOptions`, т.к. это просто декоратор для интерфейса　`IApiEx<TOptionsType, TResultType>` и `IApi<TOptionsType, TResultType>`.

Т.к. я не смогу контролировать то что будет передаваться в методы через интерфейс, мне нужно как-то ограничить наследуемые публичные классы от того что бы не мог пользователь просто написать новый класс с унаследованием от интерфейса к примеру `ISearchOptions` и сделать так что бы к примеру из метода `Uri Zip();` будет возвращаться `null`.

Это можно как нибудь проверить и быть уверенным в том что например у меня есть класс `SearchOptions`, и как-то жестко проверить является ли интерфейс именно этим классом, а не каким нибудь левым?

Или же может можно подставить какой нибудь класс/интерфейс декоратор который не позволит подставить левый класс?

[image: Диаграмма]

Comment: "Левый" класс реализующий ваш публичный интерфейс, будет принадлежать к левому же пространству имен. Следовательно на это отличие можно опереться. А с другой стороны зачем искусственно ограничивать шаловливые ручки др.коллеги? Пусть пишет свои классы  и несет ответственность за их работоспособность сам автор этих классов, в чем здесь проблема то?

Comment: Интерфейс декларирует поведение, а не реализацию. Если вы пишете публичный интерфейс и используете его в коде, то вам не должно быть важно как именно интерфейс реализован. Если на какие то методы реализация возвращает null - то это проблема реализации, а не интерфейса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Давайте попробуем разобрать разные варианты.

1. Проверять тип в рантайме. Если передан неправильный тип, бросать исключение или ещё как-то реагировать. Это гарантирует правильную работу (после устранения ошибок), но выявится только в процессе исполнения.
2. Передавать конкретный тип, а не интерфейс. Если уж есть требования на точный тип, то его и используйте. Вроде, всё просто.
3. Написать тест(ы). В тесте проходим по всем сборкам проекта, находим все типы, реализующие этот интерфейс. И проверяем, не появилось ли лишних типов. Если есть лишние - билд-процесс прерывается. Имхо, способ может гарантировать надёжность. Но нужен налаженный CI.
4. Развитие предыдущего способа. Написать Roslyn-analyzer. Этот анализатор делает то же, что и тест: ищет типы, реализующие интерфейс. В него жёстко забиты разрешённые типы. Достоинство: выдаёт предупреждения прямо по ходу написания кода. Недостаток: при малейшем изменении разрешённых типов нужно переписывать анализатор (перекомпилировать, деплоить, подключать к проекту). Ну и конечно, анализатор должен быть подключен к проекту. И программисты должны писать код не в Блокноте, а в IDE, которая поддерживает анализаторы.

Comment: Ну, анализатор можно по идее параметризировать (например, атрибутами).